# How to make /dev/input/mouse0 accessible for wine?

Tags: usb, mouse, wine

I have a gaming mouse (specifically Genius DeathTaker) and its Windows driver. The configuration app (e.g. setting the meaning of the buttons) runs fine under wine. However, when I click "Apply", nothing happens.

I believe it has something to do with the fact that wine does not "see" the mouse at all.

I found out that there is a folder for mapping devices from Linux to wine. So

`ls -l ~/.wine/dosdevices/`

has the following output:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user 10 Jan 22 19:38 c: -> ../drive_c
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user 10 Feb 15 16:23 com1 -> /dev/ttyS0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user 10 Feb 15 16:23 com2 -> /dev/ttyS1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user 10 Feb 15 16:23 com3 -> /dev/ttyS2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user 10 Feb 15 16:23 com4 -> /dev/ttyS3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user  1 Jan 22 19:38 z: -> /
```

Next, I found that if I do

`cat /dev/input/mouse0`

and start moving the mouse, I see characters appearing in my console. So I read [this forum post](https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=27320), but even after that I don't know what to do.

Comment: So mouse doesn't work? Does it work in windows without configuration/drivers? If not, first problem is that linux probably don't have a driver for it…

Comment: The mouse itself works, the problem occurs when I try to assign functionalities to its buttons.

Comment: Configuration utility just does nothing? Try to `echo ooo > /dev/input/mouse0` and look at error message. But I think that it isn't problem with access but with fact that windows use different driver for it and wine doesn't emulate (yeah, in this case it IS emulation) it.

Comment: `sudo echo ooo > /dev/input/mouse0` says `bash: /dev/input/mouse0: Permission denied`. Kindof expected (at least in my point of view), since mouse is an input device. I solved the problem in the meantime by downloading virtualbox, installing windows into it, installing the driver and successfully updating the mouse. However, it is not a very nice approach.

Comment: You make a common mistake here: `sudo echo ooo > /dev/input/mouse0` executes `echo` as root, but writes as user! Try `echo ooo | sudo tee /dev/input/mouse0` instead.

Comment: Ah, that was silly, sorry. The output is just `ooo`, no errors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89811/discussion-between-val-and-karlosss).